# Where to reference Cordova injected JS files from external Web site application

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

I have an external Web based application that runs as an iOS app using PhoneGap and Cordova.  I copied the Cordova JS files into my external Website so that after the app launches and is online it makes a window.location.href call to the external website.

```
<script src="webapp/ios/cordova.js"></script>
<script src="webapp/ios/cordova_plugins.js"></script>
<script src="webapp/plugins/cordova-plugin-device/www/device.js"></script>
<script src="webapp/plugins/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/www/inappbrowser.js"></script>
```

Since PhoneGap injects these Cordova files into the packaged app in a local storage area, I would like to be able to reference the local storage so that I always get the current and correct Cordova files.  The following script works for cordova.js on iOS, but I can't get it to work on an Android and I'm not sure where the other JS files are located.

```
<script src="cdvfile://localhost/bundle/www/cordova.js"></script>
```

Any suggestions on where these files are located on the final Cordova packages for iOS and for Android apps?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cdvfile://localhost/assets/www/cordova.js"></script>
```